# Como assinar pdf com certificado digital em PHP + Apache + OpenSSL?

Tags: php, apache, certificado-digital, openssl, assinatura-digital

Configurei o servidor apache para utilizar https, gerei o certificado do servidor e do cliente com o openssl, gostaria de saber como criar assinatura digital em documentos PDF através do certificado do cliente, e também como validar a assinatura. O objetivo é assinar laudos digitais em PDF. 
Segue duas imagens do servidor realizando autenticação através de certificado
Quem puder ajudar desde já sou grato!

[image: Essa é a imagem de autenticação de servidor] 
[image: Servidor Autenticado]

Comment: vc conseguir solucionar esse problema? Estou trabalhando na mesmo assunto e não sei por onde começar ou o que pesquisar. Se puder compartilhar o seu conhecimento eu fico grato!